# YouTube user feed parsing from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube

I am trying to make a script to get the JSON feed of a specific user latest 2 uploads on YouTube. I tried to use this script

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Set variables needed for query
var URL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/";
var UserName = "MyUsername";
var jsonFormat = "/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=2";
// Construct the JSON feed of the YouTube user's channel
var ajaxURL = URL + UserName + jsonFormat;
// Get the last videos of the YouTube account, parse it into HTML code
$.getJSON(ajaxURL, function(data){
     var htmlString = "";

    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){       
        // Here's where we piece together the HTML
        htmlString += '<iframe class="videos" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/';
        htmlString += item.id;
        htmlString += '?autoplay=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    });

    // Pop our HTML in the #videos DIV
    $('#videos').html(htmlString);

});
```

I have been using a similar script for parsing a flickr's JSON and it's working fine.. What might be going wrong with YouTube's feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've placed the API return from YouTube into a javascript object `data`, but keep in mind that YouTube also encapsulates the returned object in an object called `data`.

Therefore, in line 14, when you begin iterating through the data set:

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
```

... should actually be:

```
$.each(data.data.items, function(i,item){
```

Here is your code (corrected) placed into a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Up3W7/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a great help